# Unity Dialogue boxes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialogue where the dialogue stops at a given count and then continues after a certain event happens. I've set the number of sentences to 6 at first and I did manage to make the conversation stop after the 3rd sentence

```
 by setting the if statement in DisplayNextSentence() to ==> [sentence.Count == 3]
```

and make the player do something else but I don't know how to make the NPC continue its dialogue after finishing that certain event.

can you please enlighten me on how to do this? I did watch some youtube video but those videos either confused me or they didn't explain how that certain part work in detail but I found this method somehow easier to understand in my case.

container

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue {

//name of npc
public string name;

//sentences of the npc
[TextArea(3,10)]
public string[] sentences;
}
```

another class

```
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

//calls the Dialogue class 
public Dialogue dialogue;

//triggers the dialouge
public void TriggerDialogue()
{
    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
}
}
```

manager

```
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {

private Queue<string> sentences;

public Text NPC_nameText;
public Text NPC_DialogueText;

void Start () {
    sentences = new Queue<string>(); 
}

public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
{
    //Changes the name of the Name Text to given name
    NPC_nameText.text = dialogue.name;

    sentences.Clear();

    //goes through the whole array of sentences
    foreach(string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
    {
        sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
    }

    //displays the sentences
    DisplayNextSentence();
}

public void DisplayNextSentence()
{
    //condition if array sentence is finished looping
    if (sentences.Count == 0)
    {
        //ends dialogue and goes to the next UI
        EndDialogue();
        return;
    }   

    //Sentence appears in queue waiting for each sentence to finish
    string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
    StopAllCoroutines();

    StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
}

void EndDialogue()
{
    Debug.Log("End of Conversation");
}

IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
{
    //types the characters for each sentence
    NPC_DialogueText.text = "";
    foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
    {
        NPC_DialogueText.text += letter;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

}